# HTML, CSS - Form stretch after dropdown opens

Tags: html, css

I have HTML page divided by div's ,
one of the textboxes is an autocomplete:
[image: The textbox at the beginning]

The HTML code:

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" class="acDoc ui-autocomplete-input"  
                       data-bind="ac:Doctors, acSelected: selectedDoctor, acLabel: 'Name', acValue: 'Value',
     acMax: 10, acMinLength: -1, acDelay: 300"  />
            </div>
```

when the autocomplete opens, the whole form stretches:

[image: whenthe autoComplete open]

i want the autocomplete opens up over the text boxes that is beneath
without stretching the form.

Comment: What's the code of the doctors list div ? it should be positioned absolutely with z-index and that's it .

Comment: Doctors is a list that defined in the js file,
should i position the div that contains the autocomplete?

Comment: Let me see the code to give you the accurate answer .

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `position` property to your autocomplete and specify it to `absolute`. 

 From the documentation of `position: absolute`

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout ...

To position the element afterwards you could use the `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` properties (*remember to add `position: relative` to the parent for this to work*).

**Note**: you might need to specify the `z-index` of the absolutely positioned element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: absolute;` on the div that contains the autocomplete content. Then, you can style it accordingly.

Comment: the position: absolute is on the div that contains the autocomplete?
can you explain, im new witch css.

Comment: So, you need to target with css the div that appears below the autocomplete input field (the one that is actually moving the rest of your content). Then, use on it position:absolute; and z-index: 99;  In this way, the content will be above your other elements, instead of making room for itself and pushing them below. Check documentation on position: absolute; for more info if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Make parent div `position:relative` and autocomplete popup `position:absolute`